# CentOS image is not running?

Tags: docker

I downloaded centos base image executed in background as daemon and then tired to get in the terminal and couldn't get in.

My Host is Ubuntu 16.04.

Here are the steps I executed:

Host OS Version Ubuntu16.04

```
 root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web# lsb_release -a No LSB modules are
 available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
 Release:        16.04 Codename:       xenial
 root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web#
```

Started docker by following commands

```
root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web# docker run -d --name=my_centos centos
Unable to find image 'centos:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/centos
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
da71393503ec: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:1a62cd7c773dd5c6cf08e2e28596f6fcc99bd97e38c9b324163e0da90ed27562
Status: Downloaded newer image for centos:latest
63f4b8fce1bd44253bb420436da3ad5b8f532b253fc9e74ff52ad1b2f9844251
root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web# docker exec -i -t my_centos bash
Error response from daemon: Container 63f4b8fce1bd44253bb420436da3ad5b8f532b253fc9e74ff52ad1b2f9844251 is not running
```

No idea why it is exiting

```
root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
63f4b8fce1bd        centos              "/bin/bash"              18 minutes ago      Exited (0) 18 minutes ago                       my_centos
f0ca8b9f4fa5        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes               80/tcp, 443/tcp     my_nginxtemp
bb9ab4958c33        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour            80/tcp, 443/tcp     boring_aryabhata
886d174f641d        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                  80/tcp, 443/tcp     mad_fermat
root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web#
```

Started the container but no idea why it is exiting

```
root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web# docker start 63f4b8fce1bd
63f4b8fce1bd
root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
63f4b8fce1bd        centos              "/bin/bash"              26 minutes ago      Exited (0) 2 seconds ago                       my_centos
f0ca8b9f4fa5        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes              80/tcp, 443/tcp     my_nginxtemp
bb9ab4958c33        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour           80/tcp, 443/tcp     boring_aryabhata
886d174f641d        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                 80/tcp, 443/tcp     mad_fermat
root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web# docker exec -i -t my_centos bash
Error response from daemon: Container 63f4b8fce1bd44253bb420436da3ad5b8f532b253fc9e74ff52ad1b2f9844251 is not running
root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web#
```

PS: Can someone disable the restriction to post once every 90 mins ??? Learning has to be spontaneous and interactive.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for running `centos` container in `detached` mode. 
Try the following...

`sudo docker run -d -it centos`

Answer (score 3):

if you look at the Dockerfile of the latest image of CentOS, you will notice the last line, [from here](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/2ba488ba6746fe664fa849a1c78e3204b7d3c90e/docker/Dockerfile):

`CMD ["/bin/bash"]`

So you launch a container that has a shell, it exists and that is all.

Try:

`docker run -it --name=my_centos centos sleep infinity`

or any variant.

By the way, when you do

`root@jim-Ubuntu1504:/home/jim/web# docker exec -i -t my_centos bash`

you suppose that your container is running, which here, is not.

Check with:

`docker ps -a --filter="name=my_centos"`

that your container is up.

Comment: I agree with you and you are right.My purpose is still not served. Making it run to infinity doesn't server any purpose. It is like having a Unix server but you can't do much with it, what is the use of that? How to make it usable so we can install other software update kernel etc?

Comment: I guess you want to run, based on a CentOS, a web server (like nginx, Apache, Lighttpd...) a Database (PostGreSQL, Oracle, MariaDB...) a CMS (Wordpress or any...) or anything else. It is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the image in interactive mode to be able to connect to it.

`docker run -it centos`

The `-it` instructs Docker to allocate a pseudo-TTY connected to the container’s stdin; creating an interactive bash shell in the container.

You can expect this after running that command.

`docker@default:~$ docker run -it centos
[root@0c3c7d59b91c /]#`

Answer (score 2):

As we try to start container, it execute bash, and bash is not able to find controlling terminal due to which docker container for centos immediately stopped as it forms. To provide it terminal as well as run it in detach mode you can use:

```
docker container run -it --name centos7 -d centos:latest
```

This will run docker container in detach mode and also assign controlling terminal to bash due to which container will not stop.
Later to enter into container you can use:

```
docker container exec -it <container-id> bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing something like that.

I downloaded ubunutu.20 image from docker hub and customized and installed so many services on that image and committed locally.

I can up a container with `docker run -dt .......`

But when I try to up via `docker-compose.yml` it always restart.

My command: `#docker run -dt --restart=always --name  my_container -p 443:443 registry.mydomain.com:5000/my_image:1.0.5`

and my `docker.compose.yml` file.

```
version: "3.5"

services:
    my_servicename:
        image: registry.mydomain.com:5000/my_image:1.0.5
        restart: always
        name: my_container
        ports:
           - 443:443
        networks:
          - my_network
networks:
    my_network:
        driver: bridge
```

```
$ docker history -H my_image:1.0.5
IMAGE          CREATED         CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
f5fe3f7a9d1f   14 hours ago    /bin/bash                                       202MB     comment-1
<missing>      14 hours ago    /bin/bash                                       210MB     comment-2
```